# Integrating react-native-popup-menu with react-native-navigation

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, react-native-popup-menu

As stated in `react-native-popup-menu` [docs](https://github.com/instea/react-native-popup-menu#basic-usage) to use it we have to wrap our root `App` component with the component `MenuProvider`. In `react-native-navigation` we have no control over that container since it is managed by the native side so is there a workaround to integrate `react-native-popup-menu` with `react-native-navigation`?

Comment: You still have control over your root component, `App.js` will export the `Navigator` created by `react-native-navigation`. You can just wrap that with `Menu-provider`

Comment: @AdamRoberts How!! According to `react-native-navigation` setup, we do not have `App.js`. Instead in `index.js` we register an `appLaunchedListener` in which we call `setRoot` passing a regsitered component identifier